# ASP.NET Change the current webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working at a problem in ASP.NET.

I have to create 2 windows (i think that I need to make web forms, i don't know why they said windows) one is the login form, when i press ok and the username and password is ok, I need to
show my second window (webform)
How can I do that?

I tried to do

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form = new Form2();
            form.SetFocus("id");
        }
```

But it gives me error

```
A form tag with runat=server must exist on the Page to use SetFocus() or the Focus property.
```

What should I do?
Am i right, I have to do separate webforms for thoose windows?
This is the picture from the problem that they provided
[image]

Comment: it's not classical asp, it's asp.net, I changed your tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use webforms you can just use the following code to redirect to second form:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                 Response.Redirect("Webform2.aspx");
        }
```

Comment: Works,thanks! Do you think that there could be a better way to make 2 windows?

Comment: maybe you need to open popup window with second form, not closing first? You can use JavaScript for this. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: Hm, probably not, the problem is from the national contest for C#, other programming language should not be necesarry.